# Born-Oppenheimer approximation: electronic wave function and nuclear kinetic energy term?

Tags: approximations, molecular-dynamics, born-oppenheimer-approximation

**The Born-Oppenheimer approximation in a nutshell**

Given a molecule's Schrödinger equation

$$
[\hat{T}_N + \hat{T}_e+\hat{V}_{NN}(\textbf{R})+\hat{V}_{eN}(\textbf{r}, \textbf{R})+\hat{V}_{ee}(\textbf{r})]\lvert \psi(\textbf{r}, \textbf{R})\rangle = E\lvert \psi(\textbf{r}, \textbf{R})\rangle 
$$

The Born-Oppenheimer approximation lets us separate this problem in two simpler problems by assuming that the wave function can be written as

$$
\lvert \psi(\textbf{r}, \textbf{R})\rangle \sim \lvert \psi_e(\textbf{r}, \textbf{R})\rangle \otimes\lvert \psi_N(\textbf{R})\rangle \equiv  \lvert \psi_e(\textbf{r}, \textbf{R})\rangle  \lvert\psi_N(\textbf{R})\rangle
$$

Based on the observation that *nuclei* and *electrons* move at very different time scales. In the approximation above (*adiabatic approximation*), $\psi_e(\textbf{r}, \textbf{R})\rangle$ depends on $\textbf{R}$ parametrically. By assuming this separable wave function and remembering that there are two separated time scales, we can imagine solving the electronic problem first (assuming fixed nuclei) and the nuclear problem afterwards (assuming electrons settle instantaneously). In this sense we can make the following approximations:

- Since the electronic kinetic energy doesn't act on the $\textbf{R}$ coordinates $\Longrightarrow \hat{T}_e \lvert \psi_e \rangle \lvert \psi_N \rangle \sim \lvert \psi_N \rangle \hat{T}_e \lvert \psi_e \rangle$
- This is going to be my question $\Longrightarrow\hat{T}_N \lvert \psi_e \rangle \lvert \psi_N \rangle \sim \lvert \psi_e \rangle \hat{T}_N \lvert \psi_N \rangle$
- We can assume that over electrons time scales nuclei are not moving $\Longrightarrow\hat{V}_{eN}\lvert \psi_e \rangle \lvert \psi_N \rangle \sim \lvert \psi_N \rangle\hat{V}_{eN}\lvert \psi_e \rangle $
- Over nuclei time scales, electrons adjust instantaneously $\Longrightarrow\hat{V}_{NN}\lvert \psi_e \rangle \lvert \psi_N \rangle \sim \lvert \psi_e \rangle\hat{V}_{NN}\lvert \psi_N \rangle $
- The nuclear wave function doesn't depend on $\textbf{r}$ $\Longrightarrow\hat{V}_{ee}\lvert \psi_e \rangle \lvert \psi_N \rangle \sim \lvert \psi_N \rangle\hat{V}_{ee}\lvert \psi_e \rangle $

These approximations let us write the Schrödinger equation as

$$
\lvert \psi_N \rangle \big[\hat{T}_e +\hat{V}_{eN}+V_{ee}\big]\lvert \psi_e \rangle + \lvert \psi_e \rangle \big[\hat{T}_N+\hat{V}_{NN}\big]\lvert \psi_N \rangle = E \lvert \psi_e \rangle \lvert \psi_N \rangle
$$

in which we can recognize the (electronic) sub-problem

$$
\big[\hat{T}_e +\hat{V}_{eN}+V_{ee}\big]\lvert \psi_e \rangle = E_{el} \lvert \psi_e \rangle
$$

then we can imagine solving this (electronic) sub-problem for fast time scales, assuming nuclei are not moving, and subsequently substitute the resulting energy in the nuclear equation (acting as an effective potential) and solving this equation for slow times

$$
\big[E_{el}(\textbf{R})+\hat{V}_{NN}+\hat{T}_N\big]\lvert \psi_N \rangle = E_{tot}  \lvert \psi_N \rangle
$$

**Questions**

- Is this summary of the Born-Oppenheimer approximation correct?
- I pretty confident about all the steps besides the second approximation, namely $\hat{T}_N \lvert \psi_e \rangle \lvert \psi_N \rangle \sim \lvert \psi_e \rangle \hat{T}_N \lvert \psi_N \rangle$. I have been reading several explanation that justify this passage noticing that $\textbf{P}_N\psi_e \sim \frac{1}{M}\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\textbf{R}}\psi_e \sim \frac{1}{M}\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\textbf{r}}\psi_e \sim \frac{1}{M}\textbf{p}_e \sim \frac{m}{M}$ but I am not sure why. Is there a standard/rigorous way to see why this approximation is correct?